# Parse tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need help in parsing the below HTML tag  without any regex. Need to extract the string `'House NO /2012/'`

```
<p class="cold" style="clear:both">House NO /2012/</p>
```

Comment: adel if below answer was help full please remember to accept left check mark on the answer

Answer (score 1):

*How about the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = BeautifulSoup('<p class="cold" style="clear:both">House NO /2012/</p>', features="html.parser")

text = html.find('p', {'class':'cold'})
print(text.get_text())
```

---

```
House NO /2012/
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 ways to get it done :

1. BeautifulSoup (Uses Css Selectors)
2. lxml (Uses Xpath Selectors)
3. Regular Expressions (Uses patterns)

Here is the code :

```
# pip install bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<p class="cold" style="clear:both">House NO /2012/</p>'
html = bs(html, "html.parser")

paragraph_text = html.find('p') # or you can use find('p', {'class':'cold'}) if you have more p tags
print('BeautifulSoup:' , paragraph_text.text)


# pip install lxml
from lxml import etree

html = '<p class="cold" style="clear:both">House NO /2012/</p>'
source = etree.fromstring(html)
paragraph_text = source.xpath('//p') # or you can use //p[@class="cold"]
print('lxml:' , paragraph_text[0].text)


import re

html = '<p class="cold" style="clear:both">House NO /2012/</p>'
match = re.search(r'>(.*)<' , html)
print('Regular Expressions:' , match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
BeautifulSoup: House NO /2012/
lxml: House NO /2012/
Regular Expressions: House NO /2012/
```